# ASP.NET MVC 3 Nested Master Page - How do I use it in my cshtml view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

I have these 2 master pages - Site.Master and Blog.Master
I want to know how can I use the Blog.Master in my cshtml view?

Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
   <title>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="phPageTitle" runat="server" />
   </title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <div style="clear:both">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="phAppMenu" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
         </div>         
      </div>

      <div style="clear:both;min-height:500px">
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server">       
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>

      <div style="clear:both">
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="phFooter" runat="server">       
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is blog.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Masters/Site.Master" %>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="iphPageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="phPageTitle" runat="server">
      This is the page title
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="iphTopMenu" ContentPlaceHolderID="phTopMenu" runat="server">
      Home | Browse | Search | Post | New | Featured | Recommended
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="iphContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
      Main Content goes here
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="iphFooter" ContentPlaceHolderID="phFooter" runat="server">
      This is the footer
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Here is my Post.cshtml where I want to use the Blog.Master:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ShowPostViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Post.Title;
}
<section>
    <article>        
        <div style="overflow:hidden">
            <div style="overflow:hidden">
               <header>
                  <b>@Model.Post.Title</b><br />
                  Author: @Model.Post.Author | Id: @Model.Post._id
               </header>
               @Html.Raw(Model.Post.Content)               
               </div>
            </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an aspx master with a razor view is not directly supported, but there are workarounds. More info here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx